# Print a pyramid of numbers in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

Okey, I actually don't really know how to print a pyramid in python and even worse I need to get this:
[Pyramid of n numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqUa4.png)

The length of the pyramid is asked to the user

Here's the code.

```
n = int(input("\n Enter the lenght of the triangle.. "))

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n - i):
        print(" ", end = " ")
    for k in range(i):
        print("*", end = " ")
    print()
```

[Here is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49zKv.png)

Comment: can you show your effort?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take time to review the [tour] and [ask]. Include a clear explanation of what you're trying to do and how your requirements are not met, and include a [mcve].

Comment: Ok!! Im sorry it's my first time using this platform.  I apologize and thanks for teaching me how to ask. I already have some code.
I'll learn how to ask here and then I'll post again what I have done. 
@ tod  @PJProudhon

Comment: Please add that code to to your question to improve it, so that you can be helped

Comment: @JesusA.GarridoCordero you can add your code using the `edit` link just below your question.

Comment: Man I'm so ashamed I don't know much about how to use stack.. I'm a quick learner though so I really appreciate your patience guys.. And also for willing to help :)

Answer (score 1):

One of the options:

```
import numpy as np
a = int(input())
def pyram(a):
    n = np.zeros(a)
    hal = int((a+2)/2)+1
    n[:(hal-1)] = range(1,hal)
    n[(hal-1):] = np.array(range(1,hal-1))[::-1]
    print(n)
for i in range(1,a*2,2):
    pyram(i)
```

Comment: it says: np is not defined..

Comment: @Jesus A. Garrido Cordero ok, fixed) np is numpy library